# All packages installed, but network manager does not allow adding of vpn

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I work on 16.10

I try to use network manager for my vpn connections (openvpn) and installed the following packages:

```
network-manager-openvpn 
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
openvpn
network-manager
network-manager-gnome
network-manager-openconnect-gnome
network-manager-openconnect
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-pptp-gnome
network-manager-vpnc
network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

So I would say I installed everything needed to be able to enter/use a vpn tunnel through network manager.

However when I click "VPN Connections" it shows a grayed out "Add a VPN connection..."

[image: result when VON connections is clicked]

Comment: I am currently on a window system, so can't reproduce the problem. But my personal favorite is [Fruho](https://fruho.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you go to 'Edit Connections' and select 'Add' in the popup window then you should be able to add VPN connections.